# Update Multiple Rows in SQLite Trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Is it possible to update multiple rows in an SQLite Trigger? See below for my trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "saved_tiles_reference"
 BEFORE DELETE ON favourites
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE saved_tiles SET reference_count = reference_count - 1 WHERE id = (select tile from favourite_tiles where favourite = OLD.id);
    DELETE FROM favourite_tiles WHERE id = OLD.id;
END;
```

As you can see I want to reduce the reference count on saved_tiles by 1. The saved_tiles I want to update are defined using the select statement in the where clause.

This trigger works but for only the first entry it comes across.

**Edit**

`saved_tiles` belong to its parent `favourites` and they're joined by the table `favourite_tiles`. Here is my database structure

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for favourite_tiles
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "favourite_tiles";
CREATE TABLE "favourite_tiles" (
     "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     "favourite" integer NOT NULL,
     "tile" integer NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT "fk_favourite" FOREIGN KEY ("favourite") REFERENCES "favourites" ("id"),
     CONSTRAINT "fk_tiles" FOREIGN KEY ("tile") REFERENCES "saved_tiles" ("id")
);
INSERT INTO "main".sqlite_sequence (name, seq) VALUES ("favourite_tiles", '2');

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for favourites
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "favourites";
CREATE TABLE "favourites" (
     "id" integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for saved_tiles
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "saved_tiles";
CREATE TABLE "saved_tiles" (
     "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     "reference_count" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
INSERT INTO "main".sqlite_sequence (name, seq) VALUES ("saved_tiles", '1');

-- ----------------------------
--  Triggers structure for table favourite_tiles
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER "increment_tile_reference"
 BEFORE INSERT ON favourite_tiles
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- Type the SQL Here.
    UPDATE saved_tiles SET reference_count = reference_count + 1 WHERE id = NEW.tile;
END;

-- ----------------------------
--  Triggers structure for table favourites
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER "saved_tiles_reference"
 BEFORE DELETE ON favourites
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- Type the SQL Here.
    UPDATE saved_tiles SET reference_count = reference_count - 1 WHERE id = (select tile from favourite_tiles where favourite = OLD.id);
    DELETE FROM favourite_tiles WHERE id = OLD.id;
END;
```

Comment: What are the relationships between the tables?

Comment: Added the database structure to the question

Comment: This does not answer my question. Which columns are foreign keys?

Comment: Sorry left off the foreign keys for some reason. Added them to the edit now. The `saved_tiles` are tied to the `favourites` in the `favourite_tiles` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I solved it.

Instead of using `id = (select....`, I used `id IN (select ...` as follows in the modified trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "saved_tiles_reference"
 BEFORE DELETE ON favourites
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE saved_tiles SET reference_count = reference_count - 1 WHERE id IN (select tile from favourite_tiles where favourite = OLD.id);
    DELETE FROM favourite_tiles WHERE favourite = OLD.id;
END;
```